# Sending an email via SMTP connection in Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, smtp, send-email

I am trying to use the SMTP connection in a Power Automate flow in order to customize the "From" field (customer doesn't want emails from me, SP list, or Microsoft PowerApps, rather an email account I can't get added to).  Does anyone have experience with this connection in Power Automate?  I'm not sure what my SMTP server name is.  Any help would be great!
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps.

1. Click ... three dots in email connector.
2. Create new connection and use here generic service account that you are using usually for your connectors. You should not use your own account here.
3. In from Email , add no.reply@.... valid email address. Your company must have some no.reply@ or auto.reply@ kind of email address.
4. that account address that you are using in step-2 must have permissions to account that you are using in step-3 to send email.

[image]

Comment: Thank for the response!  When I create a new connection, it asks for an SMTP Server Address.  Would I use something like "smtp.office365.com"?  I'm not sure

Comment: Could you please share the screenshot where it asks for Smtp

Comment: I just edited the original post and added a screen shot of my error message.